# у меня проблема с кнопками в телеграме

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

я хотел создать на юзербот в питоне которой автоматически кликет на кнопки

Кнопки выглядит вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

проблема заключается в том что клик кнопки не работает

```py
import asyncio
from telethon import TelegramClient, events
from telethon.tl.functions.channels import JoinChannelRequest
from telethon.tl.custom.messagebutton import MessageButton
from telethon.tl.custom import MessageButton

api_id = ''  
api_hash = ''  

client = TelegramClient('session_name', api_id, api_hash)

channel_username = ''  #username канала
bot_username = ''  # usernameтелеграм-бота

async def handle_channel_message(event):
    print("Сообщение из канала:", event.message.text)
    await client.send_message(bot_username, 'найти')

@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=[bot_username]))
async def bot_message_handler(event):
    print("Bot Message:", event.message.text)

    if 'https://t.me/' in event.message.text:
        channel_link = event.message.text.split('https://t.me/')[1].split()[0]
        await client(JoinChannelRequest('https://t.me/' + channel_link))
        await asyncio.sleep(2)
        buttons = getattr(event.message.reply_markup, 'buttons', [])

        for row in buttons:
            for button in row:
                if isinstance(button, MessageButton) and '♻️ Проверить' in button.text:
                    try:
                        await button.click()
                        print(f"Успешно нажали кнопку '♻️ Проверить'")
                    except Exception as e:
                        print(f"Произошла ошибка при нажатии кнопки '♻️ Проверить': {e}")


@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=[channel_username]))
async def channel_message_handler(event):
    await handle_channel_message(event)

async def main():
    await client.start()
    await client.run_until_disconnected()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```